# Showing red code - project working fine but showing few methods in red color- android studio Flamingo

Tags: android, android-studio-flamingo

I have updated android studio Flamingo yesterday and my exiting project showing code in red color
FYI-  I am able to run project.

Restart caches , update libraries , changes compile versions SDK version , change java version
all I have done but not solved yet.

[Please find image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcZM5.png)

Comment: Once try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: already Did many times